# Intersection Observer - Play Different Audio Depending where on page

Tags: javascript

```js
if(!!window.IntersectionObserver){
  let target = document.querySelector('#testme');
    let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    let isPaused = false; /* flag for auto-pausing of the audio */
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => { 
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if(entry.intersectionRatio!=.5  && !audio.paused){
                audio.pause(); isPaused = true;
            }
            else if(isPaused) {audio.play(); isPaused=false}

        });
    }, {threshold: .5}); 
    observer.observe(target) ;
}

else document.querySelector('#warning').style.display = 'block';
```

```html
<!-- some warnings, for demo purposes -->
<strong id="warning" hidden>IntersectionObserver is not supported by your browser, so you can't see the effect. Check its browser support <a href="https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver" target="_blank">here</a>.</strong>
<noscript>⚠️ JAVASCRIPT IS DISABLED IN YOUR BROWSER!</noscript>
<div  style="height:600px">
<h1>Click video just to trigger the ability to auto play audio on site, then as you scroll through the page, the respective audio should pause/play depending if it's in the view</h1>

<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls="" height="200px"></video>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr>


<!-- audio files -->    
<div id="testme" style="height:600px; background-color:#CCC">
<audio controls loop src="https://truefa-znfmrrlhm9.live-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/random_music.mp3" height="10"></audio>
</div>

<hr>
<audio id="testme" controls loop src="https://truefa-znfmrrlhm9.live-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/random_muisc2.mp3"></audio>
```

I'm trying to play different audio depending where the user is on the page by leveraging `intersection observer`

However, the respective audio is not pausing and playing when the various divs are in view. Not sure what I'm missing here for the code to function accordingly...

```
if(!!window.IntersectionObserver){
  let target = document.querySelector('#testme');
    let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    let isPaused = false; /* flag for auto-pausing of the audio */
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => { 
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if(entry.intersectionRatio!=.5  && !audio.paused){
                audio.pause(); isPaused = true;
            }
            else if(isPaused) {audio.play(); isPaused=false}

        });
    }, {threshold: .5}); 
    observer.observe(target) ;
}

else document.querySelector('#warning').style.display = 'block';
```

https://codepen.io/truefa/pen/PoBWZLV

Comment: Please add a [mcve] _in the question itself_ and not just a link to an external resource that might not be accessible for whatever reason (temporarily offline, blocked, ...) -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75043066/edit) your question instead of [deleting and re-posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75042888/intersection-observer-play-different-audio-depending-where-on-page) it like this one.

Comment: **1)** An `id` must be unique... Use `class` instead. **2)** `querySelector` will get the first matching element only. Look for `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @LouysPatriceBessette I changed the code to ```let target = document.querySelectorAll('div.testme');```  nothing happened...

Comment: Open the console... You now have an error. You should run a loop to initiate an observer on each target.